# Jenkins Linux Slave Output

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm new to jenkins and need a little help. Ultimately I want to sync some files from version control, tar them, scp them. Problem is I can't get any console output from Jenkins slave. The slave is online and my job is successful but its not giving me the output I would expect. To test i did this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo bob
```

Which completes just fine but I get this

Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on blahblah in workspace /buildsync
Triggering blah » default
blahblah » default completed with result SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS

How can I see the actual output produced by the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Project was wrongly configured